# Connect to remote SSH session while using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn, protocols

I am currently working with a SVN repository which I access using the SSH protocol. I would like to locally access the same repository from a Windows machine, with a graphical user interface. I tried to reach this goal by using TortoiseSVN.

**What I did:** First of all, I generated a ssh key pair using PuTTY, saving the private one on the Windows machine and the public one in the remote ssh server. Then, while being on the server, I typed

```
echo path/of/public/key >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

for the public key to be accessible on the remote server.
Secondly, I configured a PuTTY session changing the connection type to SSH and changing the Host Name to 'server_name.institution.xx' (Port 22), taking into account that I usually run the following command to enter the remote server:

```
ssh username@server_name.institution.xx
```

I also went to 'Connection - SSH - Auth' to select the private key that I had previously generated to be stored inside the same PuTTY session. I set the name of the session to be 'server_name'.
Finally, I would like to checkout the remote svn server into a folder inside the Windows machine. So, after installing TortoiseSVN, I simply right-clicked on the folder, selecting 'SVN Checkout...' and then filling the window required information with 'svn+ssh://username@server_name.institution.xx/svn_repos_location' in the 'URL of repository' and with the full path of the folder where the svn repository was supposed to be checked-out. From what I understood TortoiseSVN is able to use the information stored in the PuTTY session that I created. I also read that I had to use PuTTY Pageant in order for the private key to be accessible, so I included the key on the Pageant list.

**What went wrong:** I immediately got prompted with a TortoisePlink window requesting a Password whose provenance I am unaware of. Eventually, after pressing 'Cancel' multiple times, I got an error message telling me that TortoiseSVN was unable to reach the specified 'svn+ssh://username@server_name.institution.xx/svn_repos_location' repository.
Does anyone know what this password is, and how I can get around it so to be able to successfully connect to the SVN repository, and to transfer the files there kept to the local Windows machine? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Re-read https://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html from chapter "Test using PuTTY" and fix mistakes

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.